# Regex filename with exactly 2 underscores

Tags: java, regex

I need to match if filenames have exactly 2 underscores and extension 'txt'.
For example:

```
asdf_assss_eee.txt    ->  true
asdf_assss_eee_txt    ->  false
asdf_assss_.txt       ->  false

private static final String FILENAME_PATTERN = "/^[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A- Za-z0-9]\\.txt";
```

does not working.

Comment: What results are you seeing with your current pattern?

Comment: Based on your description, *not on your code example*, why is the third one supposed to be false?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `+` after the third char class and you must remove the first forward slash.

```
private static final String FILENAME_PATTERN = "^[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.txt$";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this with insensitive flag:

```
[a-z\d]+_[a-z\d]+_[a-z\d]+\.txt
```

Or with inline insensitive flag

```
(?i)[a-z\d]+_[a-z\d]+_[a-z\d]+\.txt
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM2aE5/1)**

In case you want to shorten it a little, you could do:

```
([a-z\d]+_){2}[a-z\d]+\.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

So lets assume you want to at least one or more characters after the second underscore, before the file extension.

Regex is still not "needed" for this.  You could split the String by the underscore and you should have 3 elements from the split.  If the 3rd element is just ".txt" then it's not valid.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] data = new String[] {
        "asdf_assss_eee.txt",
        "asdf_assss_eee_txt",
        "asdf_assss_.txt"
    };

    for (String d : data) {
        System.out.println(validate(d));
    }
}

public static boolean validate(String str) {
    if (!str.endsWith(".txt")) {
        return false;
    }

    String[] pieces = str.split("_");
    return pieces.length == 3 && !pieces[2].equalsIgnoreCase(".txt");
}
```

Results:

```
true
false
false
```

### Old Answer

Not sure I understand why your third example is false, but this is something that can easily be done without regex.

Start with checking to see if the String ends with ".txt", then check if it contains only two underscores.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] data = new String[] {
        "asdf_assss_eee.txt",
        "asdf_assss_eee_txt",
        "asdf_assss_.txt"
    };

    for (String d : data) {
        System.out.println(validate(d));
    }
}

public static boolean validate(String str) {
    if (!str.endsWith(".txt")) {
        return false;
    }

    return str.chars().filter(c -> c == '_').count() == 2;
}
```

Results:

```
true
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Pattern:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_[^_]+_[^_]+\\.txt")
```

and use `.find()` instead of `.match()` in the Matcher:

```java
Matcher m = p.matcher(filename);
if (m.find()) {
  // found
}
```